# How exactly is FreeBSD kernel image built?

Tags: kernel, freebsd

I'm trying to look into the build process of the FreeBSD kernel. I added V=1 when invoking make, but still cannot get the detail of the kernel image linking stage. I can only receive a message

```
linking kernel.debug
text       data     bss     dec       hex    filename
12806916   1293908  1116688 15217512  e83368 kernel.debug
```

and the binary is just there. How can I know the details of the final linking (which object files are used and what options the linker consumes)?

Comment: Could you please, tell where the built kernel file present ? (in which directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel is built with the command "make buildkernel". If you look in `/usr/src/Makefile.inc1` at the definition of buildkernel:

```
    @echo "--------------------------------------------------------------"
    @echo ">>> stage 3.2: building everything"
    @echo "--------------------------------------------------------------"
    cd ${KRNLOBJDIR}/${_kernel}; ${KMAKE} all -DNO_MODULES_OBJ
    @echo "--------------------------------------------------------------"
    @echo ">>> Kernel build for ${_kernel} completed on `LC_ALL=C date`"
    @echo "--------------------------------------------------------------"
```

If you look in the kernel build makefile in `/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC/Makefile` (assuming you're building a GENERIC kernel) you will see that the files `kern.pre.mk` and `kern.post.mk` are included. Looking at `kern.pre.mk` you'll see the following linker definition:

```
SYSTEM_LD= @${LD} -Bdynamic -T ${LDSCRIPT} \
        -warn-common -export-dynamic -dynamic-linker /red/herring \
        -o ${.TARGET} -X ${SYSTEM_OBJS} vers.o
```

The `ldscript` files for the different architectures can be found in `/usr/src/sys/conf/`.